# How to retain date formatting during CSV export

Tags: java, gwt, date, csv, export

Is there a way to retain the date formatting when exporting to CSV? I have a GWT application. My date data for example is 03-01-2012 and 02-2012. After exporting it to CSV successfully, when I open the CSV file, those dates now look like 3/1/2012 and 2/1/2012 respectively. Is there a way to control how they will look like in the CSV? I debugged and followed the code right before they get exported and the dates are correct. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: 1.) What program do you use to open the CSV file (a pure text-editor, or rather something like Excel/OpenOffice Calc)? 2.) What library do you use to write the CSV?

Comment: 1.)I used Excel as default, and that's probably what most clients will use by default to open the exported file. 2.) I don't use any kind of special library to write to CSV. I just use com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat to format the dates which works because the dates get displayed correctly in the application, but not in Excel.

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to control the cell formatting of Excel from Java. Because I noticed that the formula bar in Excel shows the date format that I want but not the cell holding the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all I know, it's impossible to control how dates are displayed in Excel when using CSV (it can only be controlled by the Excel user's settings). We had a similar problem (with phone numbers), and the only workaround that works reliably, is to use an Excel format. We use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to write .xls files <sup>[*]</sup>, where we can set the cell type to text.

At least for phone numbers, this is necessary - otherwise Excel discards leading 0s, and treats them as numbers (making it impossible to distinguish between national and international phone numbers). For dates however, maybe it's worth considering, if it's better to simply let the user decide how the dates are displayed?

<sup>[*] We also offer to download .csv files with a warning that they're not ideal when opened with Excel.</sup>

Comment: Note: It even seems to be possible in your case to control the display style of the date cells (instead of using text cells). See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells (but I haven't tested this, so this is just a comment)

Comment: Yeah, I was discussing this with another programmer earlier and we kinda decided that at this point, it's just the way it is. I took a look at the Apache POI that you've suggested and it just seems like it will take more work just to get a minor thing done. I just wanted to make sure if there's an easier way of doing it. Anyways, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You should check out java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ).format( theDate )` should do what you want

Comment: We use the com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat class. For example DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM-dd-yyyy") will return a String that formats the date to "03-01-2012" and displays it in the application's screen. Then we take that string and put it in a String buffer along with the other data. At this point I can still see that the date strings are still showing the correct format. But when I open the CSV file, the dates get formatted to the way excel wants it to be. I'm not sure if there's a way to tell Excel from java that I want to use a certain format for those date cells.

Answer (score 2):

you can't (as far as i know) pass meta information in a CSV file. So to see the date the way you send it, you can pass it in one of the following ways (the data value is between the commas):

, 03-01-2012,
,="03-01-2012",

Comment: Don't know why no one upvoted this response more. I had a requirement where I had to send only csv, and xls was not allowed. So Apache POI was out of the question. But this solution worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you work with dates and you want to keep a smile on your face while working, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendMonthOfYear(2)
                          .appendDayOfYear(2).appendYear(4, 4).toFormatter();
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);
Date yourJavaDate = d.toDate();
... // work with java date (if needed! :( 
LocalDate outgoing = new LocalDate(yourJavaDate.getTime());
String myOutStr = outgoing.toString(formatter);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm using something similar to that and it works great. The problem I think is when Excel opens. The formula bar in Excel will show the correct format that my DateTimeFormat class produced, but the cell holding that date is showing it in a different format. So I'm not sure if there's a way to tell Excel from my Java application to format the dates in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a space before the Date value

i.e.,  sample query below

```
select ' '||to_char(mydatecolumn,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') DATEVALUE from mytable;
```

try exporting the data to CSV it will preserve it in the same format as it is being exported as TEXT and EXCEL will consider it as TEXT so will not change it to default EXCEL Date formats.